# Values added 2-7 times to database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm trying to add a new row of information into the database table I'm using and currently it sometimes adds from 2-5-7 rows of the same information into to the database but with different Id's.

I have tried to debug through the process and I don't understand why the ActionResult runs several times and adds the same information up to 7(!) times.

When I click the add button it starts to load the the next page and the values are added to the database. The problem is that about 5-6 seconds later after clicking the add button it goes back to the controller again and do the same process again witch result in a random number of 2-5-7 rows added with the same values but different id's.

I am using a simple View with editor-fields and a dropdown list to select countries and it is posted to the a ActionResult that adds the values into the database.

The ActionResult look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewsdesk(AddNewsdeskViewModel addNewsdesk)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newsdesk = Mapper.Map<AddNewsdeskViewModel, Newsdesk>(addNewsdesk);
            newsdesk.Country = _databaseContext.Countries.Single(c => c.Name.Equals(addNewsdesk.Country));
            newsdesk.Id = new Guid();

            _databaseContext.Add(newsdesk);
            _databaseContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Newsdesk");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: If your `AddNewsdesk()` method gets called numerous times (_"The problem is that about 5-6 seconds later after clicking the add button it goes back to the controller again"_), then there's your problem, not in the method itself. Is there some JavaScript on that page?

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: So, just for sure, the `Newsdesk` items are inserted repeatedly, not the countries?

Comment: I am using some javascript to prevent clicking the button when no information is filled in to the form. I have tried to comment it out but it still gets me multiple values into the database. 

GertArnold: Exactly 

Colin: I will check that out!